# How to retrieve the values from an Application.properties?

Tags: spring-boot

**Properties Snippet.**

```
# Email (MailProperties)
spring.mail.default-encoding=UTF-8 # Default MimeMessage encoding.
spring.mail.host= # SMTP server host. For instance `smtp.example.com`
spring.mail.jndi-name= # Session JNDI name. When set, takes precedence to others mail settings.
spring.mail.password= # Login password of the SMTP server.
spring.mail.port= # SMTP server port.
spring.mail.properties.*= # Additional JavaMail session properties.
spring.mail.protocol=smtp # Protocol used by the SMTP server.
spring.mail.test-connection=false # Test that the mail server is available on startup.
spring.mail.username= # Login user of the SMTP server.
some.prop = testingTesting
```

How can I retrieve springmail.protocol or multiple properties in my java classes?

**Attempt**

```
    @Component
public class MyBean {

    private final String prop;

    @Autowired
    public MyBean(@Value("${some.prop}") String prop) {
        this.prop = prop;
        System.out.println("================== " + prop + "================== ");
    }
}
```

I am currently using this method to print out my properties from my app.properties file. I want to annotate more than just one value.

```
@value "{some.prop, second.prop, 3rd.prop}") String prop, propOne, Prop2
```

is it possible to call multiple values? Also after I instantiate the properties in this class, How can I use these properties in another class?

Comment: "Also after I instantiate the properties in this class, How can I use these properties in another class?" - by passing them as parameters, the normal way you'd pass any data between classes.

Comment: Have you tried to inject `MailProperties` ?

Comment: @eis Can you show me an generic/brief example?
myBean mb = new myBean(some.prop, second.prop);
mb.getsome.prop?

Comment: @Jackie `@Bean MyBean myBean(@Value("${prop.value}") String value) { Another another = new Another(value); return new MyBean(another, value); }  `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could easily annotate more than one argument

```
 @Autowired
 public MyBean(
    @Value("${some.prop}") String prop,
    @Value("${some.prop2}") String prop2) {        
}
```

You may also `@Autowire` instance of `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`  (as method argument or instance field) and call `getProperty` method to obtain value of properties.

Injecting single properties as @Value is generally better, because does it does not tie your business logic to Spring API.

In Spring Boot you could also use annotation @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="connection") on a class to inject multiple properties. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties for details.